# Security of storing User object to session

Tags: java, security, authentication

I'm creating my own authentication system (using Java). When user is authenticated and user object is loaded from datastore, it is secure to store this user object to session and assume when user has user object in session, it is real and valid user object that has been obtained by legit login? Are there any possible security issues that I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle yes.

You alone are in full control of the session variables (the client has neither read nor wright access to these variables). If the authentication mechanism is circumvented, it is not because the user has set his own session variable (as he could for instance set the content of cookies).

This being said, there are of course ways *hack* web pages (read up on [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main), including CSRF, XSS and so on).

Answer (score 2):

Session hijacking? Possible SQL injection or XSS on your login page? A man in the middle attack?

Only a few things you should think about when designing a secure login system.

Answer (score 0):

I personally tend to do this on all my web apps but I remove or encrypt sensitive data in the user object before storing it in the session e.g. password

alternative is to populate and use a light version of the user object that will contain only the data you want in the session (i.e user id, first name. last name)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all other posts I think there is one more security issue. You are validating user against `database`only at the time of user logs in and then you set user in `session` let say when user is logged-in and`session` is active in between access is revoked in that case user will have access until his session life which is not acceptable.